# React) How do I ref to the same component (child)?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How do I ref to the same component (child)?

I want to use document.getElementById, but I want to learn the ref syntax of react.

I want to change the value of a specific component when the same components exist.

So I tried to use the id value, but that didn't work.

It has the same form as the attached image, and I want to change only the data with the red border.

Please help..

Child.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    Row,
    Col,
    Button,
} from "framework7-react";
class Child extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            keyValue: props.sendParams
        };

    }

    render() {

        if (this.props.inventoryCellDom == undefined || this.props.inventoryCellDom == null) {
            return (
                <Col width="20" id={this.state.keyValue} ref={this.cellRef} className="vmt-height-100per vmt-yt-subbox-border">
                    <span>Name : </span><br />
                    <span>Age : </span><br />
                    <span>Phone Number : </span>
                </Col>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default Child;
```

Parent

```
import Child from "./Child";
import React, { Component, Fragment,  useRef } from "react";
import {
    Row,
    Col,
    Button,
} from "framework7-react";

class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            personData: [
                {
                    name: 'Alex',
                    age: 20,
                    tier: 1,
                    row: 1,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Peter',
                    age: 14,
                    tier: 1,
                    row: 1,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Hann',
                    age: 50,
                    tier: 1,
                    row: 1,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Alex2',
                    age: 20,
                    tier: 2,
                    row: 2,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Peter2',
                    age: 14,
                    tier: 2,
                    row: 2,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Hann2',
                    age: 50,
                    tier: 2,
                    row: 2,
                }, {
                    name: 'Alex3',
                    age: 20,
                    tier: 3,
                    row: 3,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Peter3',
                    age: 14,
                    tier: 3,
                    row: 3,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Hann3',
                    age: 50,
                    tier: 3,
                    row: 3,
                }
            ]
        };
    }

    maxTier = 6;
    maxRow = 5;

    initInventoryCell = () => {
        let objR = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.maxTier; i++) {
            let objT = [];
            let inventoryCellDom = [];

            for (let a = 0; a < this.maxRow; a++) {
                let keyValue = i+"/"+a;
                objT.push(<Child inventoryCellDom={inventoryCellDom} sendParams={keyValue} key={keyValue}/>);
            }

            objR.push(
                <Row noGap key={i}>
                    {objT}
                </Row>
            )
        }

        return objR;
    }

    componentDidMount () {

    // How do I ref to the same component (child)?

    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.initInventoryCell()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Parent;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1Nwc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a callback to the ref in `Child` component.

```
for (let a = 0; a < this.maxRow; a++) {
    objT.push(<Child ref={this.getChildRefs} />);
}
```

You will receive the node via argument from the callback function, push it to the array and then the array will contain all `Child` items. You can access particular item by index.

```
getChildRefs = (node) =>{
    const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(node)
    //To push the node only if it is not available in the array already
    if(el && !this.childRefs.contains(el)){
      this.childRefs.push(node)
    }
  }
```

I have used `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` because class component(**Child**) will return a instance of  the React `Component`, findDOMNode will provide you the DOM node (HTML element) you need.

**Parent**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.childRefs = []
  }

  getChildRefs = (node) => {
    const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(node)
    //To push the node only if it is not available in the array already
    if(el && !this.childRefs.contains(el)){
      this.childRefs.push(node)
    }
  }


  initInventoryCell = () => {
    let objR = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < this.maxTier; i++) {
        let objT = [];
        let inventoryCellDom = [];
  
        for (let a = 0; a < this.maxRow; a++) {
            let keyValue = i+"/"+a;
            objT.push(<Child ref={this.getChildRefs} inventoryCellDom={inventoryCellDom} sendParams={keyValue} key={keyValue}/>);
        }
  
        objR.push(
            <Row noGap key={i}>
                {objT}
            </Row>
        )
    }
  
    return objR;
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    // this.childRefs will provide you the array of Child refs
    console.log(this.childRefs)
    }
}
```